# Compile and load class programatically from memory on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, compilation, javac, dynamic-class-loaders

I want to generate a java source file in a String, compile it to a class and load that class to run the code all from Goole App Engine (GAE). Is that possible?

I have naively attempted to use the JavaCompiler stuff that is new in Java 6, however I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.tools.ToolProvider is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

At runtime suggesting it will not work.

Further I have tried to include [jcompilo](https://code.google.com/p/jcompilo/) into my project but there is no documentation what so ever on how to go about using this really dense library project to compile a program from a string.

So how would I set out to achieve my goal?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? You'll find that App Engine is pretty locked down in order to protect the system from abuse. Is this something that could be solved with code generation at build time?

Comment: Actually I am building a software synthesizer that will be crafted by an API on the serverside and then deployed as a DEX bytecode to an app on Android. I will be parsing a custom DSL and then build a java source that I will compile. I chose java as intermediate language for flexibility. If other options exists that can be considered.

Comment: I see. Some of these things may be doable in Compute Engine (though it will then be your responsibility to ensure that this untrusted code can't talk to the Datastore, read/write to your Cloud Storage buckets, start up other instances, burn up CPU mining bitcoins, or anything else dangerous), but I doubt you'll be able to accomplish this purely in App Engine.

Comment: With software synthesizer I mean the kind that plays notes, not the one that generates software.

Comment: OK, so even if I depend on a 3rd party java compiler jar file to get my run-time compilation fix it will not work with GAE?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what you are actually trying to do. This can be done in GAE, but not with the approach of generating and compiling Java code. Have you looked into simply interpreting the DSL in Java? That would greatly limit the possible code that could get executed by this.

Comment: You may find "CUP" useful to help you parse the DSL and implement your own interpretation within the parser code: http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/ . You could apply a similar technique in Android as well, which would help with the fact that in Lollilop, the Android applications are ahead-of-time compiled.

Comment: I am using JavaCC for my DSL and I am targetting Andoid API level 9. Also software synths are rather performance sensitive so I can't rely on interpretion. I have thought about using renderscript  or similar acceleration on device, but then I would tie my application to GPU performance. I will look into CUP. Thanks!